# Copying known_hosts between computers

Tags: ssh

I have two computers, both running Ubuntu 18.04, and when I copy the `known_hosts` file for `root` between them, my SSH fails to recognize the host on the destination PC, prompting me to validate it.

What is the correct method to copy/extract the `known_hosts` file?

Comment: `known_hosts` is just a list of all the systems that have been connected to. Why would you copy it? Did you mean [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/634432/963426)?

Comment: @harrymc it's not just a "log file" - **it's storing a list of user-validated and accepted host keys**. One would (and should) copy it to determine if one is still connecting to the *same hosts* from the new machine, and no "man in the middle" attack is taking place. So copying `known_hosts` actually is more secure than not copying it.

Comment: Per the answer I linked, if you're using password-less connections then this file by itself is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Simply copying should suffice, *but* you will have to double-check the permissions - in your case: of your `.ssh` directory. SSH is known to ignore files with permissions too open (cf. man page).